# Parse array string to array object in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a page method which returns a list of integers using `jQuery.ajax();`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(typeof (response.d));
        console.log(response.d);
    }
});
```

***This is the result in Console***

```
string
[1767,3071,2744,1256,657,3374,3318,2518,3910,4107,2579,2997,1182,1260,32,3185,873,1374,35,858,3126,1911,3887,3053,298,3150,4222,2692,1397,707,3958,947,1315,4379,2265,2845,3123,3857,1140,1608,2317,2512,3280,1842,1930,4334,878,1366,522,1231]
```

I would like to stay away from trimming the square brackets and using split to then populate an array.

***All I want is to be able to run***

```
$.each(response.d, function() {
    console.log(this); // print each number in the array
});
```

***But in my case it prints each character, not each number.***

*Here's the page method if anyone is curious*

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    numbers.Add(rnd.Next(1000));
}


JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return js.Serialize(numbers);
```

Comment: Why don't you just do it on the server in the first place? Seems like the logical place to do it.

Comment: @epascarello: Last time I checked, `List<int>` was an array of integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should deserialize the javascript array into an actual javascript object.

```
var responseArray = JSON.parse( result.d )
//responseObject is now a literal javascript array, so you can iterate over it as you would any other array
```

Here's an [implementation of JSON.parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: Is JSON.parse a part of jQuery now?

Answer (score 1):

- Why don't you just return a [JSON object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) from the server.
- Set the content type to application/json.
- With the jQuery Ajax call set dataType to json.

And jQuery will parse everything for you. All you would need to do is data.yourArrayName to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set dataType:json it will parse the response as json.